# can any one help to find out what is missing this small program

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

i am trying out my first program and would appreciate if someone would tell me what is going on wrong. i wrote this program to pop up a screen with 4 choices and when i click on one of those choices it should switch screen to the next screen, please advice what did i wrote wrong because all what i am getting is the first screen then nothing when i click on the buttons thank you.

here is the program

```
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)



        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        btn1 = tk.Button(text="", fg="white", width=400, height=240, command=lambda : controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        btn1["bg"] = "white"
        mi = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Python\\trials\\pic1.gif")
        btn1.config(image=mi)
        btn1.image = mi

        btn2 = tk.Button(text="", fg="white", width=400, height=240, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        btn2["bg"] = "white"
        mi1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Python\\trials\\safety.gif")
        btn2.config(image=mi1)
        btn2.image = mi1

        btn3 = tk.Button(text="", fg="white", width=400, height=240)
        btn3["bg"] = "white"
        mi2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Python\\trials\\count.gif")
        btn3.config(image=mi2)
        btn3.image = mi2

        btn4 = tk.Button(text="", fg="white", width=400, height=240)
        btn4["bg"] = "white"
        mi3 = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Python\\trials\\about.gif")
        btn4.config(image=mi3)
        btn4.image = mi3

        btn1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EW')
        btn2.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=1, sticky='EW')
        btn3.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EW')
        btn4.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, sticky='Ew')



class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.grid()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.grid()


app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

First, all of your Buttons need to have the first argument 'self'. You did this in some places but you forgot it in the StartPage class.

Second, you need to layout your container. Add a `pack()` after you initialize it:

```
container = tk.Frame(self)
container.pack()
```

Comment: another question, what would be the code if i want every screen/page have its own title and bg color.

Comment: You can add a background color to a widget with the `bg` argument, like this: `tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='green')`. The window title can only be set by the root window, so you need to make a method that overrides `tkraise`: http://pastebin.com/Suvvi5KE Note I also added a line to keep `self.controller`.